# Automapping double nested IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, automapper

I have a rather complex situation.
I have an order:

```
 public partial class Order
    {
        public string orderNum { get; set;}
        public ICollection<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I have a view BIGVIEW:

```
 public partial class BIGVIEWVM
    {
        public string orderNum { get; set;}
        public OrderDetailsVM Order { get; set; }
        public ShipmentsTableVM Shipments { get; set; }
    }
```

The subview, `ShipmentsTableVM` is like so:

```
public partial class ShipmentsTableVM
    {
          public string somethingelse {get;set;}
          public IEnumerable<Shipment_Table_Row_VM> Shipments{get;set;}
    }
```

It's actually more complex than this, but this is the issue in its simplest form.

I have an `Order` with lots of `Shipments`. I want to make a `ProjectTo` call using AutoMapper from the `Order` to the `BIGVIEW`. The entire of the `Order` is mapped into the `OrderDetailsVM` with no problem, however, What I do not know how to do is pass the ICollection to my ShipmentsTableVM and THEN map it into the IEnumerable.

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Order, BIGVIEW>()
                .ForMember(d => d.order, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s))
                ...?
```

I thought I could take care of the mapping from the `ICollection<Shipments>` to my `ShipmentsTableVM`:

```
            cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Shipment>, ShipmentsTableVM>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Shipments, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s))
                ;
```

But this doesn't work - I get an error about Linq not being able to map things that are not an IEnumerable... but I am using an IEnumerable so I don't understand. I have tried a variety of other configurations too but I'm getting nowhere fast.

I am looking for an Automapper solution for this, as I do not want to manually do the projection in my controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve this, here is one of them.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Shipments, Shipment_Table_Row_VM>();

cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Shipments>, ShipmentsTableVM>()
.ConstructUsing(obj => new ShipmentsTableVM())
.ForMember(d => d.Shipments, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s));

cfg.CreateMap<Order, BIGVIEWVM>();
```

Comment: `Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[[MYAPP.Models.SHIPMENT, MYAPP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass proper model to subview.  try :

```
Order.Shipments
```

or

```
Model.Shipments
```

Comment: I tried this, then I have to map the ICollection<Shipments> but it seems to have an issue with `cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Shipments>, ShipmentsTableVM>()`

Comment: try `cfg. Map` instead of  `cfg.CreateMap`

Comment: cfg.Map doesn't exist